# Fill a DropDownList in .net

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I write this code to extract specific column to be added into the list, but its wrong. I want to:

```
List<Stone_Names> Stones = new List<Stone_Names>();
using (PSPlatformEntities1 p = new PSPlatformEntities1())
{
    Stones.Add(new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = p.Stone_Names["stoneName"].ToString(),
        Value = p.Stone_Names["nameID"]
    });
}
```

Comment: Does this code compile ? Does your `PSPlatformEntities1` class has a property called `Stone_Name` which of type dictionary ?

Comment: Also format your code. It is not that hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very simple get the list from db first the bind into dropdown

```
 ViewBag.DDlist= db.Stones.ToList().Select(x => new 
         SelectListItem()
                    {
                        Text = x.stoneName,
                        Value = x.nameID.ToString()
                    });
```

In view

```
                  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.modelProperty, 
                     new SelectList(ViewBag.DDlist, "Value", "Text"), 
                 "Select value", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Note: stoneName , nameID should be your table name